# Integration on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\nu$ be a measure on $[0, \infty)$ and $c > 0$ be a constant. Why is it true that:

$$
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} c^2 \left(\frac{1}{c} - \frac{1}{c + s}\right)\nu(ds) = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} s^2 \left(\frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{c + s}\right)\nu(ds) \quad ?
$$

Comment: Some context or idea or something would make this seemingly random statement/question much more interesting. Where did you find it? What do you know about measures? What about convergence? What about ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$c^2\left(\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{s+c}\right)=
\frac{c^2 \left(s+c-c\right)}{c(s+c)}=
\frac{cs}{s+c}=
\frac{s^2(c+s-s)}{s(c+s)}=
s^2\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{c+s}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, I expected there's more to it than that. ;)